# Automating named Range function in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, named-ranges

**Context**

So I have a spreadsheet with 11+ sheets, though will be adding more later. I want to dynamically name the columns using named range. I created a macro script and have been using this. Only the problem is for every sheet, I have to go to the script and change the name of the named range:

```
function NamedRanges() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.setNamedRange('TrainlineDate', spreadsheet.getRange('A:A'));
      spreadsheet.setNamedRange('TrainlinePrice', spreadsheet.getRange('B:B'));
      spreadsheet.setNamedRange('TrainlineReturns', spreadsheet.getRange('C:C'));
      spreadsheet.setNamedRange('TrainlineGrossReturns', spreadsheet.getRange('D:D'));
      spreadsheet.setNamedRange('TrainlineGeometricReturns', spreadsheet.getRange('E:E'));
      spreadsheet.setNamedRange('TrainlineRisk', spreadsheet.getRange('F:F'));
      spreadsheet.setNamedRange('TrainlineNegativeReturns', spreadsheet.getRange('G:G'));
      spreadsheet.setNamedRange('TrainlinePositiveReturns', spreadsheet.getRange('H:H'));
      spreadsheet.setNamedRange('TrainlineTimeValueMoney', spreadsheet.getRange('I:I'));
    };
```

For example, for the next tab, I have to change Trainline to Softcat.

I tried my hand at creating the columns as an array and then a for loop to create a named range according to the name in cell `B2` + the name in the headers (the 3rd row of every column). I will also be adding new columns in the future. But when I tried to log the value in cell `B2` it failed. Long story short, I am stuck. This is what I came up with thus far;

```
function NamedRange() {
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var col = ss.getLastColumn(); //Get all the columns in the sheet with data (there will be no gaps/spaces)
      var stockName = ss.getRange("B1"); // name in cell B1 (column 2, row 1)
      var headerCell = ss.getRange(3, col); // in row 3 of all columns
      var rangeName = ss.getValue(stockName);         
      Logger.log(rangeName) // test to see if the value of stockname is picked up by Appscript

// For every column, get the values in 'stockName and headerCell' and create a named range from them. 
An exception is for the second column, instead of 'Close' name, call it 'Stockname' + 'Price'.
    };
```

Here is an example of the spreadsheet format. This script though will be applicable to Aveva Group tab onwards.
[image: Data for stock(s)]

**Problem**

Typically the format of the spreadsheets will all be the same. The only difference will be the name of the stock. I want to be able to automatically set the namedRange of all columns for existing and new columns for every tab/sheet and trigger it using a custom menu (this part I can sort out myself). Is there a better way to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Create an array of all the sheet names you would like to be part of this process.
- [ForEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) sheet name, set the name ranges according to that name by concatenating the sheet name with the `namerange` name.

### Solution:

```
function NamedRanges() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      //put all the sheets here you want to include
      var sheetNames = ["Trainline","Softcat","Avast"];
      var namerng=['Date','Price','Returns','GrossReturns','GeometricReturns',
                  'Risk','NegativeReturns','PositiveReturns','TimeValueMoney'];
      sheetNames.forEach(sh=>{
          sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sh);
          namerng.forEach((nr,i)=>{
           spreadsheet.setNamedRange(sh+nr, sheet.getRange(1,i+1,sheet.getMaxRows(),1));
          });
      });
};
```

Save also this code to your script editor and it will create a menu button at the top menu of the spreadsheet file that will execute `NamedRanges`:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Name Ranges', 'NamedRanges')
  .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding :). I tried the code and thanks for the custom menu, that was convenient. I am getting this error at the moment `TypeError: sheet.setNamedRange is not a function (anonymous) @ macros.gs:8 NamedRanges@ macros.gs:6`

Comment: @Desmond sorry, typo. Check my answer again.

Comment: Great this worked! I have a quick question though. Do I have to keep typing in the column? Would it be possible to recognise a new column or use the `getLastColumns` or `getMaxColumns` function and then create the namedrange or is that not possible?

Comment: @Desmond try please my updated answer. Much faster and smaller. Make sure `namerng` elements are in the same order as the columns (starting from column `A`)

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely! Greatful for your help yet again! :)